# How set environment variable based on whether a GUI is available?

Tags: x11, environment-variables

How can I set up my .bashrc such that the value of an environment variable changes based on whether or not the current session has access to the gui / windowing system?

For example, let's say I have an environment variable that controls which diff program my VCS will use.

When I'm sitting at the machine, I'd like to use a GUI program.  However, when I connect remotely via SSH, I'd like to have it automatically use a text-based terminal diff viewer instead.

How can I check whether or not the windowing system is available?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check the `$DISPLAY` variable to see whether you're on an x display - if it's non-empty, you have a display:

```
if [ -n "$DISPLAY" ]; then
    # run GUI program
else
    # run term program
fi
```

A quick test showed this even works for X-tunneling.

Comment: Thanks!  I knew I had seen a way to do this before, just couldn't find it anywhere.